# Comparing numbers of p-values from many linear models

Tags: genetics, microarray

My current dataset has three conditions, and we've measured the activity levels of 10,000 genes in each condition. Replicated 8 times.

Using 10,000 linear models, we determine for each pair of conditions (ie for each of three contrasts) the number of genes with significantly different activity levels. This is [standard procedure](http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/limma/) for this kind of microarray data.

We find:

- 2000 genes have significantly different activity levels between A and B
- 1500 genes have significantly different activity levels between A and C
- 100 genes have significantly different activity levels between B and C

This suggests that conditions B and C are more similar to each other than to C. PCA suggests the same result.
Is there any way for us to quantify the extent to which "conditions B and C are more similar to each other than to C (ie to put a p-value on it?)

Thanks for your help, and apologies if this question is trivial.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to answering your question -  is the distribution of effect of the genes justify using a linear model (e.g: are they distributed more or less normally?)

Now to your question - I might offer to go a different way about it.  It sounds like what you are asking for is to measure the correlation (e.g similarity of behavior) between the different conditions.  A simple way to do that is to take the mean (or maybe the trimmed mean or median) of the 8 replications and then you'd have 10K triplets you can use for creating a correlation matrix (between the 3 conditions).

The second step would then be to answer the question if one correlation (say between A and B) is significantly higher then the other two correlations (say, between --A and C-- and --B and C--).  Here you can use the following nice [online tool](http://faculty.vassar.edu/lowry/rdiff.html) or you can code it yourself in R using the information given [here](http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/B8712.html).

Cheers,
Tal

Comment: (yes, the gene expression values are more or less normally distributed)

Comment: You're welcome Yannick.  I suspect what I suggest will work.  Cheers, Tal